# Using log4j in Swing application

Tags: java, swing, log4j

Our Swing application doesn't limit the number of application instance user opens that is user can run as many app instances as he likes by accessing JWS link more than once. Here my question is if I use log4j for logging many app instances(jvm) will share the same log file, right? Are there any lock issue for this or these app instances can write their logs into the same log file without conflict?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the question is: is it a good method to let all instances of your application wriite into one file. The meaning of logging is to recognize the bugs in your application. If you use the same file you won't know which instance throwed the exception and where the bug appears. May be you can change your logging-architecture so this mistake won't happen. 
Try to count the instances, or generating an instanceID and appending it to the log-file,

Comment: Yeah, I'm just thinking about using different log files for different app instances. But more effort need to be put on maintenance these log files, for instance, after user open and close the app more and more the number of log files becomes big we need a good way to clear the history useless log files. Can log4j do this?

Comment: yes, you can solve this by restricting the log-filesize by log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB
# Keep one backup file
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1

Comment: but this config may be just suitable for my first solution that is writing all instance app log files to only one file. However, if one app instance one log file (using timestamp or instanceID etc. to identify each other), the number of log files can't be easily controlled by log4j, right?

Comment: you're right, this can't be controlled by log4j. This is something you have to implement yourself...

Comment: Currently I just want to put all instances' log into one file because I don't want to take effort on maintenance log file number. Can log4j be configured like this (that is one log file can be shared by many app instances)? For default configuration, I have tried, the first startup instance will occupy the file others can't access the log file any more. Thanks.